# Why segues does not work? can not switch view

Tags: ios, swift, view, segue

**Not quite sure why the view is not changing when the button Calculate
is pressed?
What are the possible reasons for that? Could you please help?

```
import UIKit
class CalculateViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightSlider: UISlider!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func heightSlided(_ sender: UISlider) {
        var currentHeightValue = sender.value
        let roundedHeightValue = String(format: "%.2f", currentHeightValue)
        heightLabel.text = "\(roundedHeightValue)m"
    }
    
    @IBAction func weightSlided(_ sender: UISlider) {
        var currentWeightValue = sender.value
        let roundedWeightValue = String(format: "%.0f", currentWeightValue)
        weightLabel.text = "\(roundedWeightValue)kg"
    }
    
    @IBAction func calculateBMI(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var squareOfHeight = Float(pow(heightSlider.value, 2.0))
        var BMI = weightSlider.value / squareOfHeight
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
   
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You need to do a little debugging... Is `calculateBMI()` actually being called (maybe it's not connected to the right button)? If it *is* being called, check the setup for your Segue... maybe a typo? e.g. you entered "gotoResult" in Storyboard instead of "goToResult"?

Answer (score -1):

try this..

> let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "**Name
> Storyboard**", bundle: nil)
> if let push = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "**Name Storyboar
> ID**") as? **Name View Controller** {
> self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push, animated: true)
> }